# How to include a division from another webpage and put it in a division?

Tags: javascript, php, html

How can I include a div from another webpage and display it on another webpage? Can I use Iframe? Thanks for the help!

Comment: what do you mean? Post codes please

Comment: I want to include a division inside another division from another file

Answer (score 2):

If you are using `.php` in your pages you can use `include` for example

you have a `header div` let's name it `header.php`

```
<header>
  <div>
   //....
  </div>
</header>
```

you can include it on you other pages for example in your `index.php`

```
<?php include 'header.php'; ?>
```

hope this would help.

Comment: it's better to use `require_once()` or `require()` than `include()`, which only issue warning instead of error when file to be included does not exist.

Answer (score 0):

Apart from PHP include, we can use JS function to load an external HTML to current HTML.

For example, your external HTML is named as "external.html", you can load the HTML into a DIV by:

HTML

```
<div id="frame"></div>
```

JS

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#frame').load('external.html');
});
```

Note: Given that jQuery is included in the HTML page.